# How to fix WebPush 401 error for Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-push

I'm trying to develop my own notification system on my website but I have a problem. I use firebase and his keys (I'm not using VapidKeys). One thing : every works on Firefox but not on Google Chrome.

For my application I followed [this link.](https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push-php-example)

and others tutorial on how does firebase works...

```
<?php
include_once (getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT') . '/lib/include.php');
...

use Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush;
use Minishlink\WebPush\Subscription;
use Minishlink\WebPush\VAPID;

array of notifications
$notifications = array(
    array(
        'subscription' => Subscription::create(array(
            'endpoint' => 'https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1/gAAAAABcyExVQOIq3T0hJlKO6awqMrGwo0kcjjqi5mYKLddIfKcvva-2AcIMY1f1X32Zpdo3IlOqKb00eOhgUI_TTYMdmSwA6VxUjsQPgZwFmDQuvWjYnvax6yuV-WraBE9MclHMou6G', // Firefox 43+,
            'publicKey' => 'BKVJQAkW1OFebroeetQBX1gVsDXQIs8TRYOk0b7ENCK3NBhOCxqCN2uAAZ5wQq7lqS0AqTu5qkKzNHH2oMQAJes', // base 64 encoded, should be 88 chars
            'authToken' => 'PTYrPzIoW96SnYjjmSPvrg', // base 64 encoded, should be 24 chars
        )
        ),
        'payload' => 'hello !',
    ),
    array(
        'subscription' => Subscription::create(array(
            'endpoint' => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/dgSeLeTBqQs:APA91bGWVsUbkd5R9jOyqjDx5PMzuDtse1X9jGtJ3D_G_1wPehNFCq9-aEkyVSdqnzkuv5pbetE8k0rU_XrSGNvZ6WVG-7zZQJha_WvVK8zvUkGUxBsKzF6kPYMIDGZ6Qx2VjrWIbePS',
        )
        ),
        'payload' => null,
    )
    );

$webPush = new WebPush();
// send multiple notifications with payload
foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
    $webPush->sendNotification(
        $notification['subscription'],
        $notification['payload'] // optional (defaults null)
    );
}

foreach ($webPush->flush() as $report) {
    $endpoint = $report->getRequest()->getUri()->__toString();

    if ($report->isSuccess()) {
        echo "[v] Message sent successfully for subscription {$endpoint}.";
    } else {
        echo "[x] Message failed to sent for subscription {$endpoint}: {$report->getReason()}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the error that you are receiving.

Comment: [x] Message failed to sent for subscription https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/dgSeLeTBqQs:APA91bGWVsUbkd5R9jOyqjDx5PMzuDtse1X9jGtJ3D_G_1wPehNFCq9-aEkyVSdqnzkuv5pbetE8k0rU_XrSGNvZ6WVG-7zZQJha_WvVK8zvUkGUxBsKzF6kPYMIDGZ6Qx2VjrWIbePS: Client error: `POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/dgSeLeTBqQs:APA91bGWVsUbkd5R9jOyqjDx5PMzuDtse1X9jGtJ3D_G_1wPehNFCq9-aEkyVSdqnzkuv5pbetE8k0rU_XrSGNvZ6WVG-7zZQJha_WvVK8zvUkGUxBsKzF6kPYMIDGZ6Qx2VjrWIbePS` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:

Comment: You didn't include any kind of auth token for the google endpoint, so it seems likely that's why you get an Unauthorised error for that service. You specified the endpoint URL, but no other fields (unlike for the firefox one, where you included some credentials). Check what credentials the FCM API requires, and  then include them in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried with publicKey and authToken, but got same error ..

Comment: well I would not expect that the token would be the same ones you use for the Firefox one. The name of the field might not even be the same, I don't know. You need to check the documentation of that API provider specifically and find out how you authenticate. All I know is that sending _no_ authentication details is never going to work.

Comment: Yeah i know i just did like here : https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php, by the way the push message works on postman but not on my navigator ...

Comment: I know you did it based on that, I read that page before commenting. But the examples there don't show the particular API you are calling. There's an example for android.googleapis.com but not for fcm.googleapis.com . So you'll have to check what is required by that API.

Comment: Yeah i saw and its works, i just do a call curl for google chrome and an array for mozilla. thanks for your help :)

Comment: if you found the solution, you should post the working code in the "Answers" section below, and explain what you changed, so others can benefit from it in future. And of course you can get reputation points when people upvote it, too :-)